# Program only prints out last row of list

Tags: python, csv

Hello I'm trying to get this program to print out the list data for the corridor entered in the class call at the bottom. But it only prints out the very last row in the list. This program takes in a .csv file and turns into a list. Not by any means a very experienced python programmer.

```
class csv_get(object): # class to being in the .csv file to the program
     import os
     os.chdir('C:\Users\U2970\Documents\ArcGIS')
     gpsTrack = open('roadlog_intersection_export_02_18_2014_2.csv', 'rb')
     # Figure out position of lat and long in the header
     headerLine = gpsTrack.readline()
     valueList = headerLine.split(",")

class data_set(object): # place columns from .csv file into a python dictionary
    dict = {'DESC' : csv_get.valueList.index("TDD_DESC"),
    'ROUTE_NAME' : csv_get.valueList.index("ROUTE_NAME"),
    'CORRIDOR': csv_get.valueList.index("CORRIDOR"),
    'ROADBED': csv_get.valueList.index("DC_RBD"),
    'BEG_RP': csv_get.valueList.index("BEG_RP"),
    'END_RP': csv_get.valueList.index("END_RP"),
    'DESIGNATION': csv_get.valueList.index("NRLG_SYS_DESC")}

class columns_set(object): # append the dict into a list
    new_list = []
    for line in csv_get.gpsTrack.readlines():
        segmentedLine = line.split(",")
        new_list.append([segmentedLine[data_set.dict['DESC']],\
        '{:>7}'.format(segmentedLine[data_set.dict['ROUTE_NAME']]),\
        '{:>7}'.format(segmentedLine[data_set.dict['CORRIDOR']]),\
        '{:>7}'.format(segmentedLine[data_set.dict['ROADBED']]),\
        '{:>7}'.format(segmentedLine[data_set.dict['BEG_RP']]),\
        '{:>7}'.format(segmentedLine[data_set.dict['END_RP']]),\
        '{:>7}'.format(segmentedLine[data_set.dict['DESIGNATION']])])

class data: 
   def __init__(self,corridor):
       for col in columns_set.new_list: # for each column in the list new_list
            self.desc = col[0] 
            self.route = col[1]  # assigns column names to column numbers
            self.corridor = col[2] 
            self.roadbed = col[3]
            self.beg_rp = col[4] 
            self.end_rp = col[5] 
            self.designation = col[6] 

   def displayData(self): # print data for corridor number entered
       print self.desc,\
            self.route,\
            self.corridor,\
            self.roadbed,\
            self.beg_rp,\
            self.end_rp,\
            self.designation

set1 = data('C000021') # corridor number to be sent into data class
# should print all the corridor data but only prints very last record
set1.displayData()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only storing data from the current row, and overwriting it with each row. A line like `self.desc = col[0]` says "overwrite `self.desc` so it refers to the value of `col[0]`.

I hate to say it, but all of this code is flawed at a fundamental level. Your classes, except for `data`, are really functions. And even `data` is defective because it pulls in hardwired elements from outside itself.

You really should use Python's included [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to parse a CSV file into lists of lists. It can even give you a list of dictionaries and handle the header line.

Comment: Ok thanks for the response Mike. So would i change the for loop in the data class initiation?

Comment: Huh. ok well i am definetely open to suggestions as to how i can become better at programming (not a programme per se). I like to use the classes that way so that I can easily call refer to them for data or varaiables they hold. But yes they are working like functions. I am self taught on python so im sure i have many hangups. Thanks ill look into what you said.

Comment: OK so i figured out my problem and I turned those classes, which are basically functions, into methods within a single class. The program works well now so thank you very much for the help. Now i just need to figure out how to do more.